# Querying associate table with HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two Entity class with a oneToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@DynamicInsert (value = true)
@DynamicUpdate (value = true)
public class Matchs {

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long matchId;
   private int size;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "Match_Users",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="match_id"),
   inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
   private List<User> users;

      //Getters & Setters
}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@DynamicInsert (value = true)
@DynamicUpdate (value = true)
public class User {

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String lastName,firstName,password,email;

    private Date dateOfBirth;
        //Getters & Setters
  }
```

I want to get all Matchs for a particular User.This is my query:

```
 FROM Matchs WHERE User.username=:username
```

This query throws org.hibernate.QueryException. How can I accomplish this with HQL.

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be fetching the data on a column which does not exist in your `Matchs` table. I don't see any column or relationship in your `Matchs` class for `username`

Answer (score 1):

`FROM Matchs WHERE users.username=:username`
In HQL you have to specify relationship name (users), not target entity (user); what happens is you have:

```
public class Matchs {

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long matchId;
   private int size;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "Match_Users",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="match_id"),
   inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
   private List<User> users;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "Match_winners",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="match_id"),
   inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
   private List<User> winners;

      //Getters & Setters
}
```

how can, in your original query, differentiate `users` from `winners` using entity name (`User`) and not relationship name?

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<Matchs> list = session.createQuery("from Matchs matchs where matchs.users.username=:username").setParameter("username","myname").list();
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what this code does and why it works.

Comment: I tried the second approach and get the following exception:  org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [{synthetic-alias}{non-qualified-property-ref}users] with element property reference [username] [FROM com.kyrogaming.models.Matchs WHERE users.username=:user]